# Naive Bayes in R, e1071 library: fitted model gives apriori probabilities as predictions for every record

Tags: r, naivebayes

I use Naive Bayes from e1071 library. I have the following toy dataset with name `nb0.csv`

```
N_INQUIRIES_BIN,TARGET
1,0
2,1
2,0
1,0
1,0
1,0
1,1
```

Then I use the following code lines

```
library(e1071)
data = read.csv('d:/nb0.csv')
model <- naiveBayes(as.factor(data[, 'N_INQUIRIES_BIN']), data[, 'TARGET'])
```

When I type `model` I see that the model was trained somehow

```
> model    
Naive Bayes Classifier for Discrete Predictors

Call:
naiveBayes.default(x = as.factor(data[, "N_INQUIRIES_BIN"]),
    y = data[, "TARGET"])

A-priori probabilities:
data[, "TARGET"]
        0         1
0.7142857 0.2857143

Conditional probabilities:
                x
data[, "TARGET"]   1   2
               0 0.8 0.2
               1 0.5 0.5
```

However, when I make predictions on the training data I get apriori probabilities as predictions for all records

```
> predict(model, as.factor(data[, 'N_INQUIRIES_BIN']), type='raw')
             0         1
[1,] 0.7142857 0.2857143
[2,] 0.7142857 0.2857143
[3,] 0.7142857 0.2857143
[4,] 0.7142857 0.2857143
[5,] 0.7142857 0.2857143
[6,] 0.7142857 0.2857143
[7,] 0.7142857 0.2857143
```

Is this a bug of implementation or I am missing something obvious?

P.S. everything works fine with the [example](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/e1071/docs/naiveBayes)

**Correct answer**

The code

```
library(e1071)
data = read.csv('d:/nb0.csv')

data$N_INQUIRIES_BIN <- as.factor(data$N_INQUIRIES_BIN)

model <- naiveBayes(TARGET ~ ., data)
predict(model, data, type='raw')
```

leads to exactly what I wanted

Comment: I think your `naiveBayes` function could be wrong. Note that in the linked examples there is always a formula (and none in yours), and naiveBayes takes data.frames or arrays only (so `data[,'TARGET']` probably should not work)

Comment: The formula doesn't have to be set explicitely, this can be seen from `iris` example. In the same example the usage of `iris[, 5]` is shown, so `data[, 'TARGET']` must work in the same fashion. To be on the safe side I checked that `model <- naiveBayes(as.factor(data[, 1]), data[, 2])` leads to the same behaviour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was getting too long for a comment, so I'm posting as an answer. I see two or three things that could be switched:

**First**: I would recommend to call `as.factor()` outside of the model, like so:

```
data$N_INQUIRIES_BIN <- as.factor(data$N_INQUIRIES_BIN)
```

**Second**: I am unsure of whether this is what you want, but I don't see a formula in your call (note how in the examples that you posted there is always a formula), note the difference between this:

```
model <- naiveBayes(as.factor(data[, 'N_INQUIRIES_BIN']), data[, 'TARGET'])
```

and this:

```
#Here I can't claim this is the model you are looking for, but for illustration purposes:
model <- naiveBayes(N_INQUIRIES_BIN ~ ., data = data)
```

Note that, aside from calling `as.factor()` before, I also switched the data call, as this threw an error when trying your method:

> Error in naiveBayes.formula(N_INQUIRIES_BIN ~ ., data = data[, 2]) : 
>     naiveBayes formula interface handles data frames or arrays only

The same error when you reference by name:

> Error in naiveBayes.formula(N_INQUIRIES_BIN ~ ., data = data[, "TARGET"]) : 
>     naiveBayes formula interface handles data frames or arrays only

This alternative model however, outputs the following:

```
model <- naiveBayes(N_INQUIRIES_BIN ~ ., data = data)
model
#
#Naive Bayes Classifier for Discrete Predictors
#
#Call:
#naiveBayes.default(x = X, y = Y, laplace = laplace)
#
#A-priori probabilities:
#Y
#        1         2 
#0.7142857 0.2857143 
#
#Conditional probabilities:
#   TARGET
#Y   [,1]      [,2]
#  1  0.2 0.4472136
#  2  0.5 0.7071068
```

Note again that the conditional and A-priori probabilities calculated with this function call are different from yours.

**Finally**, predict (again, following the examples from the help file):

```
#Here, all of the dataset is taken into account
predict(model, data, type='raw')
#             1         2
#[1,] 0.8211908 0.1788092
#[2,] 0.5061087 0.4938913
#[3,] 0.8211908 0.1788092
#[4,] 0.8211908 0.1788092
#[5,] 0.8211908 0.1788092
#[6,] 0.8211908 0.1788092
#[7,] 0.5061087 0.4938913
```

---

For completeness' sake and, regarding to the motif of the posting, the  formula from the model *was* different from what OP wanted, here is the actual call:

```
#Keep the as.factor call outside of the model
data$N_INQUIRIES_BIN <- as.factor(data$N_INQUIRIES_BIN)
#explicitly state the formula in the naivebayes
#note that the especified column is TARGET and not N_INQUIRIES_BIN
model <- naiveBayes(TARGET ~ ., data)
#predict the model, with all the dataset
predict(model, data, type='raw')
#Yields the following:
#       0   1
#[1,] 0.8 0.2
#[2,] 0.5 0.5
#[3,] 0.5 0.5
#[4,] 0.8 0.2
#[5,] 0.8 0.2
#[6,] 0.8 0.2
#[7,] 0.8 0.2
```

Comment: I changed the code according to your instructions and all looks good. I am new to R, so I cannot tell what exactly was the trigger. The formula (but there is an example that doesn't use formula), using dataframes or something else? Thanks!

Comment: I see that the formula call was actually the other way around, I'll edit the answer with the correct data, glad to help!

Comment: thanks! I also added the correct answer to the bottom of my question